# Why won't my RewriteRules play nice together?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The first part of my code works and redirects/rewrites to `new/file`. Problem occurs when I try to pass variables. They all get redirected to `new/file`

Whatever variable I try to pass in `file.php?foo=bar` redirects to `new/file` instead of `new/file/bar`.

for example:

- new/file rewrites to file.php
- new/file/2 rewrites to file.php?page=2
- file.php redirects to new/file
- file.php?page=2 doesn't redirect to new/file/2 but get's overwritten to new/file instead

My code:

```
RewriteBase /domain.com

#regular 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=no
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ new/file? [NS,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^new/file?$ file.php?redirect=no [NS]

#with variable
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9-]+)/?$ 
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ new/file/%1?  [NS,R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^new/file/([0-9-]+)/?$ file.php?page=$1&redirect=no [NS]
```

Please note that I am passing more than just `page` variables.

I'm thinking maybe a **QSA flag** is supposed to go somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=no
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ new/file [NS,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^new/file$ file.php?redirect=no [NS]
```

In line 2 you had ?. This will replace the current querystring, and page=2 is lost.

In line 3 you had a ?. Paths don't contain questionmarks. Secondly the questionmark is interpreted as an "optional letter 'e'", because it is a RegEx. So "/new/fil" would also work (try it out).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I take the question mark off the second line I'm redirected to `new/file?page=2` but it stays on new/file and not page 2.

Comment: You should move the "regular" rules to after the "with variable" rules.